# Is there any way to print debug or console message in screen of android app in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-authentication, screen, display

I am building a login page, where when no verification of mail is done, user will be displayed on screen that **mail is not verified**, this is the following code i tried doing.

```
if(user.isEmailVerified == false){
print('Email not verified')          //in console screen
return Text('Please verify email')   // in android screen 
}
```

But nothing works out, 
**assuming no syntactical errors** is there any way to display the string on the screen? 
I even tried using a new container and doing it, but no success.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use package https://pub.dev/packages/flushbar

code snippet

```
RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Flushbar(
                  title: "Error",
                  message: "Please verify email",
                  duration:  Duration(seconds: 10),
                )..show(context);
              },
              child:
                  const Text('Enabled Button', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
            ),
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flushbar/flushbar.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Flushbar(
                  title: "Error",
                  message: "Please verify email",
                  duration: Duration(seconds: 10),
                )..show(context);
              },
              child:
                  const Text('Enabled Button', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
            ),
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes You can achieve that but not in the exact manner you are thinking.You have to take `String` variable named `errorMessage` and initialise it by empty String.

```
String errorMessage='';
```

Then you can take a `Text()` anywhere in the screen containing the message.

```
Text(errorMessage)
```

Then in the error part you can set the message to the `errorMessage` variable and call `setState()`

```
if(user.isEmailVerified == false){
    print('Email not verified')          //in console screen
    setState((){
        errorMessage='Email Not Verified';
    });   // in android screen 
}
```